# infoWindow on google maps v3 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

and sorry my bad english :-S
I have a little problem.
I load json data from a external json file.
here the content of the file:

```
{
"Pizza Dach": {
    "Kategorie": "Pizza",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 13.456106,
        "Latitude": 52.51024
    }
},
"Burgeramt": {
    "Kategorie": "Burger",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 13.459539,
        "Latitude": 52.510299
    }
},
"DUDU": {
    "Kategorie": "Pizza",
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 13.415165,
        "Latitude": 52.493024
    }
}
}
```

and here is my js code:

```
var karte;
var marker;
var meineLongitude, meineLatitude;

/* Karte */

var positionsAusgabe = function(position){
    width = document.getElementById('karte').offsetWidth;
    height = document.getElementById('karte').offsetHeight;

    meineLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    meineLatitude = position.coords.latitude;

    var optionen = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(meineLatitude, meineLongitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    karte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('karte'), optionen);

    window.setTimeout(function(){

        $.getJSON('daten/restaurants.json?='+Date.now(), function(data){
            $.each(data, function(restaurant, daten){

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: karte,
                    icon: 'bilder/'+daten.Kategorie+'.png',

                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(daten.Position.Latitude,daten.Position.Longitude)
                });

(function(marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent('+daten.Kategorie+');
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

      });


            });

        //  window.scrollTo(0,1);

        });

    },1); 

};
```

Well, the problem is, that the marker are setting, with the right icon and the right position, BUT i have no idea why the infoWindow doesn't appear. Im sure that i have make something wrong in the js code, but i don't find the error.
Someone has an idea?
Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: The code posted contains javascript errors.  Could you run it through jslint or put it in a fiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: @ geocodezip: I don't see errors inside the code(at least no syntax-errors which will stop the execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code will do nothing:

```
  (function(marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent('+data.Kategorie+');
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });

  });
```

you define a function, but you didn't execute it.

Try this:

```
  (function(marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(daten.Kategorie);
                infoWindow.open(karte, marker);
            });

  }(marker,daten));
```

However, there is no need for this function. You're already inside a function(the `$.each`-callback), when you make the marker-variable local it will not be overwritten:

```
        $.each(data, function(restaurant, daten){

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: karte,
                icon: 'bilder/'+daten.Kategorie+'.png',
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(daten.Position.Latitude,daten.Position.Longitude)
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(daten.Kategorie);
                infoWindow.open(karte, marker);
            });

        });
```